# External IDs unavailable in Apex Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, externalid

I have a number of external Ids in my SFDC environment, but I can't see them in the Data Loader or in the Jitterbit Data Loader.

Any ideas?

Data Loader:

[image: Data loader settings]

Field settings:

[image: Field settings]

Comment: Field level security?

Answer (score 2):

Are the fields actually on the account record? Maybe an obvious question but it's easy to overlook the obvious and would explain what's going on here; also double check that you've not got a sandbox/production mismatch.

I don't think FLS is the issue as I'm pretty sure you'd still see the field name etc. via the API, you just wouldn't have access to data inside it.

Comment: They are definitely on the Account object. They are other external Ids that I've created on other objects and they're not visible either. It's not a FLS issue as it's a Professional Edition org, with API enabled.

Comment: If you setup the project in Eclipse, and include the Objects can you see the fields in the Account's XML file?